# Linq Stored Procedure insert gets no result

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

Im trying to insert data with a stored procedure with Linq To SQL.
I get no error message and my data does't get inserted.
The code is in vb because i also work with xml in this project.

Code

```
        Using db As New booksDataContext()

        db.testprocedure("kkk")
        db.SubmitChanges()

        End Using
```

Stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE testprocedure

(
@test varchar(50)
)

AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test (testcolum)
VALUES (@test)
END
```

I can se it goes in to this function when i debugging and it's returning 0

```
<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name:="dbo.testprocedure")>  _
Public Function testprocedure(<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType:="VarChar(50)")> ByVal test As String) As Integer
    Dim result As IExecuteResult = Me.ExecuteMethodCall(Me, CType(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod,MethodInfo), test)
    Return CType(result.ReturnValue,Integer)
End Function
```

I have done a Select that works perfekt so its not wrong with the datacontext

```
  Sub SelectAllBooks()

    Dim db As New booksDataContext()

    For Each book In db.SelectBooks("Madde")

        Dim title = book.title
        Dim author = book.author
        Dim genre = book.genre
        Dim price = book.price
        Dim publish_date = book.publish_date
        Dim description = book.description
        Dim bookid = book.bookid


        Console.WriteLine(title & " " & author & " " & genre & " " & price & " " & publish_date & " " & description & " " & bookid)

    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you run SQLProfiler can you see your statement getting executed?

Answer (score 0):

Check this a very good tutorial:

[LINQ to SQL (Updating our Database using Stored Procedures)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/23/linq-to-sql-part-7-updating-our-database-using-stored-procedures.aspx)

Also, Check the `test` table if the values are inserted correctly.

Unless documented otherwise, all system stored procedures return a value of 0. This indicates success and a nonzero value indicates failure.

[RETURN (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: The OP states "my data doesn't get inserted."

Comment: @Jodrell OP also says "I can se it goes in to this function when i debugging and it's returning 0"

Comment: The data doesn't get inserted.
In my insert the return value is Nothing and on my select that works the return value = Database Query (i put a watch on it in VS)

If i execute the SP manually it works (right click on it and pick execute)

Comment: I also did the Delete and Update funtions it's the same as Insert.
Someone know the reason way only selects work and not Insert Update Delete, i must do something wrong

Comment: Check this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/23/linq-to-sql-part-7-updating-our-database-using-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: Thanks i have looked at that one i but i still can't see whats wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a primary key on your table?  That is the only way I am able to get the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE methods to work through LINQ.